# What's wrong with my REGEX while using VI editor?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text document like so:

```
<table width="10">
</table>
```

I open the document with the VI editor.  I want to replace all instances of width="somenumber" with nothing.  I issue this command in the VI editor:

```
:0,$s/width="[\d]+"//gc
```

VI says no pattern found.   I also tried this and it doens't work:

```
0,$s/width="[0-9]+"//gc
```

This one below worked:

```
:0,$s/width="\d\d"//gc
```

What's wrong with my first two expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have **two** errors in your regexp!

First, use `\d` without `[]`s around it.  You probably mix it with character classes like `:alpha:`, `:digit:`, etc.

Second, Escape the `+` sign.  By default you should escape it.

So your regexp would be:

```
:0,$s/width="\d\+"//gc
```

And, please, read help before posting on stackoverflow:

```
:h :s
```

You may also be interested in this help section:

```
:h magic
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
:0,$s/ width="\d\+"//gc
```

`\d` isn't recognized inside a character class (or rather, it's recognized as the letter `d`), and `+` without a backslash isn't recognized as a metacharacter by `vim`'s BRE.  You also probably want the space before `width` to be eliminated.

Comment: I just tried this and it says no pattern found 0,$s/width="[0-9]+"//gc

Comment: How about just removing the square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

It will only work with widths of two digits, won't it?